# Create a Transpose and GroupBy Matrix Dataframe Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transform, transpose

I have the follow table with the columns names ID,STORE and PUSH available.

With the PUSH values for each row(in this case I just have a ID, but the table contains more), I would like to create the second table(yellow one in the picture).

Then the target is:
create new columns for each STORE(listed 7 adh,ayc,maeg,rot,witz,mar,bud), where each store will receive the value from the PUSH column.

The result expected is the yellow table which I will add in the same dataframe used to generate the ID,STORE,PUSH tables.

Any help would be very appreciated !

```
the code I tried was:
df['ADH'] = combined_sf2.groupby('PNO') 
['Push'].transform() 
df['AYC'] = combined_sf2.groupby('PNO') 
['Push'].transform()
df['ADH'] = combined_sf2.groupby('PNO') 
['Push'].transform()
df['MAEG'] = combined_sf2.groupby('PNO') 
['Push'].transform()
df['ROT'] = combined_sf2.groupby('PNO') 
['Push'].transform()
df['WITZ'] = combined_sf2.groupby('PNO') 
['Push'].transform()
df['BUD'] = combined_sf2.groupby('PNO') 
['Push'].transform()
df['MAR'] = combined_sf2.groupby('PNO') 
['Push'].transform()
```

But is retuning just 1 value for all lines

[image]

Comment: Could you post some example data as text, not images, and also what code you've tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8008776/peter-leimbigler, I added the code I tried. I can not built the table, because all columns are coming from other columsn calculations combinations, I tried to summaryze the idea to the picture detailed.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# pivot to get the right table format (ID as index, STORE as column
# and PUSH as values).
# the second part (with the loc) is here to repeat the lines according
# to each ID.

pd.pivot(df, index='ID', columns='STORE', values='PUSH').loc[df.ID]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17025688/fiphrelin, I`m having the follow error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pivot'

Comment: it is customary to import pandas as pd. From your error, i'm guessing you defined a function in your code as pd

Comment: I added it before "import pandas as pd", but still this "error pivot_simple() got multiple values for argument 'index'"

Comment: I can't find any reference to the pivot_simple function in the pandas api. Do you mind providing the few lines of code you used ?